# How to communicate or send data from one ionic application to another ionic application?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I want to communicate my ionic application(Subscriber Application) with another ionic application(Merchant Application).
Here the requirement is I want to send the transaction success message to the another application once the payment is done by hand.
I have tried few work grounds like using PUSH service but not make it worked.
Is there any idea around to make it possible?

Comment: yes thry this one http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/push-from-scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share a database between both merchant and subscriber apps. Like Parse Server or something that will allow server side code execution.

1/ Make payment (handle securely on server)

2/ Backend server confirms to client side payment made successfully returning payment successful to subscriber and sending a push to the merchant to alert them.

3/ On opening the merchant app, request data from database to show details of transaction etc.

Parse server: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server

Answer (score 0):

I think as suggested by Ant I'm using Baasbox for my application and it has built in push server where I can send the push notification to the logged in users.
I'm also sending a notification when the transaction is sent to database and Merchant can get the list with the swipe down feature.
One problem I'm facing in IONIC is the push notification won't work when the application is in the foreground. so I'm unable to catch the events when a push notification arrives.

Comment: If you are using $cordovaPush then you should be able to monitor the device state on notification receipt like so: `$scope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function (event, notification) { if (notification.foreground == "1") { Do stuff here as received in the foreground } else { do stuff here as received in background } }`. Post a new question if you can't get it going and I'll help out if I can.